# Set up Jenkins,Docker, Kubernetes ci/cd on Azure

Tags: azure, docker, jenkins, kubernetes

I want to create a CI/CD on Azure with Jenkins, Docker, Kubernetes, starting from simple.

I already went through the **Voting-app** tutorial **Tutorial: Prepare application for Azure Container Service (AKS)** [Azure tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-prepare-app) The tutorial covers the steps:

> 1 - Prepare application for AKS  2 - Create container registry ACS  3
>   -Create Kubernetes cluster  4 - Run application

The application is working.

The next step I want to do, is to integrate Jenkins. I am following the tutorial **Continuous deployment with Jenkins and Azure Container Service** I couldn´t follow the tutorial because is too advanced to understand the commands from the files. For example, the way they deployed jenkins using the file [deploy-jenkins-vm.sh](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-voting-app-redis/blob/master/jenkins-tutorial/deploy-jenkins-vm.sh)

Instead of that, I went to the Marketplace on Azure and created "Jenkins" and via the Azure UI, set up the configuration. Jenkins is now running on localhost:8080

From another video tutorial [Hands-on Docker, Jenkins CI/CD Azure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UyYTrOCLuBs)  I shared the cluster kubeconfig to my remote jenkins host:

> $ sudo scp ~/.kube/config
>   anjenkins@jenkins9999.australiaeast.cloudapp.azure.com:/var/lib/jenkins/config

It worked.

Then, from the same video tutorial they run a bash file

```
#!/bin/bash
# Jenkins Bootstrap for ACS Kubernetes
set -x #echo on
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mekenthompson/kubectl/master/kubectl -O ~/kubectl
chmod +x kubectl
sudo cp kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
sudo mkdir /home/tomcat/.kube
sudo cp config /home/tomcat/.kube/config
sudo chown -R tomcat:tomcat /home/tomcat/.kube
sudo usermod -aG docker tomcat
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart
set +x #echo off
```

From the repository [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mekenthompson/example-voting-app/master/jenkins/jenkins-bootstrap.sh). It didn´t work for me

```
+ chmod +x kubectl
+ sudo cp kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
+ sudo mkdir /home/tomcat/.kube
mkdir: cannot create directory '/home/tomcat/.kube': No such file or directory
+ sudo cp config /home/tomcat/.kube/config
cp: cannot stat 'config': No such file or directory
+ sudo chown -R tomcat:tomcat /home/tomcat/.kube
chown: invalid user: 'tomcat:tomcat'
+ sudo usermod -aG docker tomcat
usermod: group 'docker' does not exist
+ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart
sudo: /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh: command not found
+ set +x
```

But my question is, what is the next step after I shared de kubeconfig to my jenkins remote host. I am just copying and pasting, but not knowing , what is happening

Form the tutorials, they seem to me, too advanced and I don´t know what is going on, or what exactly should be done.

From the Azure **Voting tutorial** they have another file, to set up Jenkins [config-jenkins.sh](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-voting-app-redis/blob/master/jenkins-tutorial/config-jenkins.sh), but as well I don´t know what needs to be done

What exactly I should do, Do you know other resources or links to follow.

I have already jenkins, an Azure Container Registry, Azure Container Service, and the voting app.

Comment: You need to create docker and tomcat user. the user and its home directory is not present. and run that script using bash if its bash script..

Comment: the  /home/tomcat/.kube directory should be on my local file? How about the docker usermod: group 'docker' does not exist, where should I create a group docker

Comment: @JogendraKumar in that case, I can use the commands from github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-voting-app-redis/blob/master/… #Docker, #Azure CLI, #Kubectl, and #Configure access.... would that be enough?

Comment: We have to create the users where you running that script. I haven't read the document which you are a followup. That's script is required that users.

Comment: Now is working, it was easier to follow the tutorial from azure.

Comment: What was the issue you can update that will helpful for someone.

Comment: There were two ways I found and followed to install Jenkins on Azure. One via the Azure UI (video Hands-on Jenkins,Docker) and the second via the tutorial Jenkins on Azure From the second one, they do it more "automated" and I thought that it will be difficult to understand the commands, but at the end is pretty easy, is the option I decided at the end. From the video tutorial they use ascript to install dependencies on Jenkins, (the ones described above). I had some errors, mainly because some directories were not found, but I dont know if I should create them by my own

Answer (score 2):

We're working on an open source project called [Jenkins X](https://jenkins-x.io/) which is a proposed sub project of the Jenkins foundation aimed at automating CI/CD on Kubernetes using Jenkins pipelines and GitOps for promotion across environments.

If you want to see how to automate CI/CD with multiple environments on Kubernetes using GitOps for promotion between environments and Preview Environments on Pull Requests you might wanna check out [my recent talk on Jenkins X at DevOxx UK](https://jenkins-x.io/demos/devoxx-uk-2018/) where I do a live demo of this on GKE. Though Jenkins X works on [AWS, AKS and GKE and other kubernetes clusters too](https://jenkins-x.io/getting-started/).